# GeoIP for configuration into nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, geoip

I'm trying to compile geoip into nginx. When doing `./configure --with-http_geoip_module` I get the following error.

```
./configure: error: the GeoIP module requires the GeoIP library.
You can either do not enable the module or install the library.
```

I've tried any combination's for trying to find the geoip module for nginx with apt-get and I'm having no luck. If anyone can point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
root@ip-10-112-39-42:~# apt-cache search geoip
....
libgeoip-dev - Development files for the GeoIP library
....
root@ip-10-112-39-42:~# apt-get install libgeoip-dev
```

Comment: Insightful answer. I should rephrase the question too "How do I find packages on my system."

Answer (score 4):

For Centos/RedHat and other yum-based:

`yum provides geoip-devel`

In my case it is in `epel` repo.